# How to truncate a list in css with "..." and then add "+3" more items in the list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In css/ js/ angular, how would I produce the following result in the UI:

> Cart: apples, oranges, cherries ... +10

With a list of varying amounts, and the "+10" being the number of additional items in the list.

This will be contained in an angular directive with varying container widths to hold this content. Is there some sort of filter in angular that does this already? If there isn't what is the best way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the truncation with the angular filter [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo):

**Controller**

```
$scope.things = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

**View**

```
<p>Things: {{ things | limitTo: 3 }}</p>
```

This would produce the result:

```
Things: [1, 2, 3]
```

**EDIT**: There is no built-in filter or directive for AngularJS that also specifies the remaining elements in the object, you would need to write a custom directive to achieve that.